# SwiftUI - Scale, Zoom and Crop Image

Tags: swift, swiftui

Edited with [link to repository](https://github.com/dougdot3/CropTestSwiftUI).

I am using SwiftUI and so don't have access to the 'cropping view'. I am using gestures instead of ScrollView to capture a zoom level and offset (x and y) of an image. I am unable to return an image which crops properly based on these factors.

*It seems as if SwiftUI itself might be a factor. Perhaps the offset of the image within the view needs to be accounted for in determining offsets and zoom levels?*

I have the image and I have the following values from the gestures on the view to represent scale and x/y position:

```
 @State var scale: CGFloat = 1.0
 @State var currentPosition: CGSize = CGSize.zero
```

The current attempt, which gets closest for the function called:

```
func prepareImage( ) {

        let imageToManipulate =  UIImage(named: "landscape")
        let currentPositionWidth = self.currentPosition.width
        let currentPositionHeight = self.currentPosition.height
        let zoomScale = self.scale
        let imsize = imageToManipulate!.size

        var scale : CGFloat = self.frameSize.width / imsize.width
        if imsize.height * scale < self.frameSize.height {
            scale = self.frameSize.height / imsize.height
        }
        let croppedImsize = CGSize(width: (self.frameSize.width/scale) / zoomScale, height: (self.frameSize.height/scale) / zoomScale)
        let xOffset = (( imsize.width - croppedImsize.width ) / 2.0) - (currentPositionWidth / zoomScale)
        let yOffset = (( imsize.height - croppedImsize.height) / 2.0) - (currentPositionHeight / zoomScale)
        let croppedImrect: CGRect = CGRect(x: xOffset, y: yOffset, width: croppedImsize.width, height: croppedImsize.height)

        let r = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:croppedImsize)
        let croppedIm = r.image { _ in
            imageToManipulate!.draw(at: CGPoint(x:-croppedImrect.origin.x, y:-croppedImrect.origin.y))
        }
        self.croppedImage = croppedIm
        self.photoIsFinished = true
    }
```

However, as you will see in the repository, when combining both zoom/scale and x/y offsets it is always 'off' a bit.

As well, when you try to crop to a square image the amount it is 'off' can be quite significant.

Comment: While I find that SwiftUI is *very* lacking with regards to images, not much in the code posted actually seems to be due to SwiftUI - I'm not seeing an `Image` View. So let's dig a bit deeper - are you dealing with a `UIImage` (about the *only* thing SwiftUI currently uses) or something else like a `CGImage` or `CIImage`? Trust me, it matters. And If you *are* actually dealing with a view - why??? Manipulate the image, not the view, which only renders the image. Even if that means dropping into UIKit.

Comment: Ah well yes - apologies - I am working with a UIImage. I have edited my question. I only mention SwiftUI because I can find bits of code which include using a view.bounds etc and so I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong in trying to manipulate a UIImage as above.

Comment: I'm going to need to do cropping - of a CIImage - soon. I really cannot address a CGImage, ubt UIImage/CIImage have one thing in common - size (for a UIImage) and extent (for a CIImage). Since my need is for a CIImage I'll use the CICrop filter - adjusting everything via the frame of a UIView. Basically, (1) let the "target" of your crop be a UIView with a border, (2) adjust it to the actual image size, (3) crop the CIImage, and (4) serenader is, letting `scaleAspectFit` render it properly on the screen. Not sure if that will help you at all - but with SwiftUI's limitations, who knows.

Comment: @dfd I updated with a code repository. You might find it useful when you get to that point. I've tackled what I think you're planning to do, but still can't get the function to return the correct result. See my edited question and repository.

Comment: Link to the repository is broken again

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [Asperi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61307605/14035205)  , I have implement a lightweight swiftUI library to crop image.Here is the library and demo.[Here](https://github.com/zhxf2012/CropImageView)

The magic is below:

```
    public var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy  in
           // ...
                        
                        Button(action: {
  // how to crop the image according to rectangle area
                            if self.tempResult == nil {
                                self.cropTheImageWithImageViewSize(proxy.size)
                            }
                            self.resultImage = self.tempResult
                        })  {
            Text("Crop Image")
                .padding(.all, 10)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 1)
                .padding(.top, 50)
        }
                    }
  }

func cropTheImageWithImageViewSize(_ size: CGSize) {

    let imsize =  inputImage.size
    let scale = max(inputImage.size.width / size.width,
                    inputImage.size.height / size.height)

    
    let zoomScale = self.scale

    let currentPositionWidth = self.dragAmount.width * scale
        let currentPositionHeight = self.dragAmount.height * scale
    
    let croppedImsize = CGSize(width: (self.cropSize.width * scale) / zoomScale, height: (self.cropSize.height * scale) / zoomScale)
     
    let xOffset = (( imsize.width - croppedImsize.width) / 2.0) - (currentPositionWidth  / zoomScale)
    let yOffset = (( imsize.height - croppedImsize.height) / 2.0) - (currentPositionHeight  / zoomScale)
    let croppedImrect: CGRect = CGRect(x: xOffset, y: yOffset, width: croppedImsize.width, height: croppedImsize.height)
          
    if let cropped = inputImage.cgImage?.cropping(to: croppedImrect) {
       //uiimage here can write to data in png or jpeg
        let croppedIm = UIImage(cgImage: cropped)
        tempResult = croppedIm
        result = Image(uiImage: croppedIm)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

The answer was provided via the GitHub repository by [juanj](https://github.com/juanj)

```
let imageToManipulate =  UIImage(named: "landscape")
let zoomScale = self.scale
let imsize = imageToManipulate!.size

var scale : CGFloat = self.frameSize.width / imsize.width
if imsize.height * scale < self.frameSize.height {
 scale = self.frameSize.height / imsize.height
}
let currentPositionWidth = self.currentPosition.width / scale
let currentPositionHeight = self.currentPosition.height / scale
let croppedImsize = CGSize(width: (self.frameSize.width/scale) / zoomScale, height: (self.frameSize.height/scale) / zoomScale)
let xOffset = (( imsize.width - croppedImsize.width ) / 2.0) - (currentPositionWidth / zoomScale)
let yOffset = (( imsize.height - croppedImsize.height) / 2.0) - (currentPositionHeight / zoomScale)
let croppedImrect: CGRect = CGRect(x: xOffset, y: yOffset, width: croppedImsize.width, height: croppedImsize.height)

let r = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:croppedImsize)
let croppedIm = r.image { _ in
            imageToManipulate!.draw(at: CGPoint(x:-croppedImrect.origin.x, y:-croppedImrect.origin.y))
        }
self.croppedImage = croppedIm
self.photoIsFinished = true
```

The full code, demonstrating how to allow a user to zoom and pan an image within a frame in a SwiftUI view, and then crop the result to a new image can be [viewed in the repository](https://github.com/dougdot3/CropTestSwiftUI).

Comment: Hi @dot3, the github repository url doesn't seem to exist anymore. Could you please check? I would like to have a look into it. Thanks

Comment: @atulkhatri and anyone else looking - juanj still has his version up: https://github.com/juanj/CropTestSwiftUI

Comment: @MichaelHudson the repo doen't exist